# How to increase the number of executors that process a certain stage in Spark Streaming/Kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to read data from Kafka (1 topic, 5 partitions) using Spark Streaming Direct approach. In order to increase parallelism for processing the data, I set `Dstream.repartition(60)`. However it seems that only 5 executors are running in each stage of each batch of streaming?

I had set these parameters:

```
--num-executors 20 
--executor-cores 4
--executor-memory 3G
--driver-memory 3G
--spark.default.Parallelism 60
```

My confusion is:
I want to decrease processing time, so I try to increase the number of `Vcores`, but this method doesn't seem to work. Why? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> (1 topic, 5 partitions) using Spark Streaming Direct approach.... It seems that only 5 executors are running

That's all you're going to get. You cannot have more than one consumer per topic partition.

The only way you'll get Spark (or any Kafka Consumer group) is to scale out more executors is to repartition the topic itself, and this is a different terminology than repartitioning in Spark

Note: increasing the number of partitions of a topic is possible, but the keys of the messages will no longer be one-to-one for the retention policy of the topic for the last message written before the repartition

After you repartition a topic, I believe you must restart the Spark application as it won't fetch new topic data dynamically

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. It's really weird. I checked the result, found that when I set `Dstream.repartition(60) ` ,  `--num-executors 20 `, `--executor-cores 4` as mentioned above, 20 executors started. Everything is OK. The problem that I described appeared when I set `Dstream.repartition(100) ` ,  `--num-executors 50 `, `--executor-cores 2`  ..  How to explain it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but still you can only have as many initial executors as topics. The repartition in Spark is potentially expensive operator and depends on the keys of the messages, I believe